# Which PCM data format to choose I2S or Left-Justified?

Tags: dac, i2s

I can't find any information which PCM data format is better - I2S or Left-Justified and why I should use one format over another. Is there a difference or it doesn't matter which one I'll use?

Comment: If you need to talk to something that only supports one, pick that.  Otherwise up to you.

Comment: As written this is opinion based. There also does not appear to be any prior research and no details on what PCM is being used to interface with, which might affect answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither is better, unless there are some limitations in the used devices regarding the protocol. Select something that both devices can support.